# Finding exact words in text, excluding quoted words

Tags: javascript, regex

In the javascript code below I need to find in a text exact words, but *excluding* the words that are between quotes. This is my attempt, what's wrong with the regex? It should find all the words excluding `word22` and `"word3"`. If I use only `\b` in the regex it selects exact words but it doesn't exclude the words between quotes.

```
var text = 'word1, word2, word22, "word3" and word4';
var words = [ 'word1', 'word2', 'word3' , 'word4' ];
words.forEach(function(word){
    var re = new RegExp('\\b^"' + word + '^"\\b', 'i');
    var  pos = text.search(re); 
    if (pos > -1)
        alert(word + " found in position " + pos);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we'll use a function to escape the characters of the word, just in case there's some that have special meaning for regexp.

```
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30851002/240443
function regExpEscape(literal_string) {
    return literal_string.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\/\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

Then, we construct a regular expression as an alternation between individual word regexps. For each word, we assert that it starts with a word boundary, ends with a word boundary, and has an even number of quote characters between its end, and the end of string. (Note that from the end of `word3`, there is only one quote till the end of string, which is odd.)

```
let text = 'word1, word2, word22, "word3" and word4';
let words = [ 'word1', 'word2', 'word3' , 'word4' ];
let regexp = new RegExp(words.map(word =>
'\\b' + regExpEscape(word) + '\\b(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)').join('|'), 'g')

text.match(regexp)
// => word1, word2, word4

while ((m = regexp.exec(text))) {
  console.log(m[0], m.index);
}
// word1 0
// word2 7
// word4 34
```

EDIT: Actually, we can speed the regexp up a bit if we factor out the surrounding conditions:

```
let regexp = new RegExp(
  '\\b(?:' + 
  words.map(regExpEscape).join('|') + 
  ')\\b(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', 'g')
```

Comment: This is probably the better solution because it balances the quotes around something. Mine wouldn't match something like `"word2` or `word2"` where it starts or ends with a quotation mark, but isn't surrounded by one.

Answer (score 1):

Your excluding of the quote character is wrong, that's actually matching the beginning of the string followed by a quote. Trying this instead

```
var re = new RegExp('\\b[^"]' + word + '[^"]\\b', 'i');
```

Also, this site is amazing to help you debug regex : https://regexpal.com

Edit: Because `\b` will match on quotation marks, this needs to be tweaked further. Unfortunately javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, so we have to get a little tricky.

```
var re = new RegExp('(?:^|[^"\\w])' + word + '(?:$|[^"\\w])','i')
```

So what this is doing is saying

```
(?:         Don't capture this group
^ | [^"\w]) either match the start of the line, or any non word (alphanumeric and underscore) character that isn't a quote
word        capture and match your word here
(?:         Don't capture this group either
$|[^"\w)    either match the end of the line, or any non word character that isn't a quote again
```

Comment: If seeking `word2`, you'd only find it if the string contained `bword2e` or similar, as your "not a quote" assertions are not null-width, and will have to consume a character each.

Comment: since javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, this is a little more annoying, but see if that update works for you @ps0604